# Whats new in XAML 2009?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

What are new important staff in XAML 2009?

Comment: There are lots of new features in XAML 2009!
You can't use them on Visual Studio or other compiled XAML!

Rephrasing: There are 0 usable features in XAML 2009!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just have a look at this

http://www.wpftutorial.net/XAML2009.html

and

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/tags/xaml+2009+features/